# can you write 1.0 as number in JavaScript (there are only zeros after the decimal point)?

Tags: javascript, numbers

I'm trying to solve a challenge involving finding the mean of an array but the output must be a number with a decimal point (4.0) Is it possible to do this in JavaScript? if the answer is no is there a programming language that can do it

Comment: It wouldn't be a number any more if you wanted that output - it would be a string.

Comment: That challenge should be specifying the data type of the output: string or number?

Comment: _“is there a programming language that can do it”_ isn’t really a useful question to ask. Don’t confuse the number _representation_ with the _number itself_, for any given number type. The literals `4.0` and `4` result in the same value JS. There are other programming languages, where they don’t, but a specific data type of a specific programming language should be specified. If not, either the challenge is very vague or your question is. And even if so, have you at least _tried_ passing that challenge with _any_ number representation?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
var num= 5;

num.toFixed(1);
```

it will return 5.0

Comment: this will return a string not a number

Comment: you can typecast it into Number by using Number(num), but this will remove  .0  from it

Comment: you can use another programing language like  C, CPP, or java where you can use float data type